# Asp.Net - Ler Ficheiros

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core

Olá, Eu preciso novamente da vossa ajuda.
Eu estou a trabalhar num projeto em que consiste ler ficheiros XML e guardar os dados numa tabela.
Eu já consigo fazer isso, mas estou com um problema.

Este é um exemplo de um ficheiro XML.

```html
<products>
<product>

<name>Ball</name>

<price>15</price>

<quantity>2</quantity>
<description>
<comment>aaa</comment>
</description>
<description>
<comment>bbb</comment>

</description>
<age>

<number>12</number>

</age>

</product>
</products>
```

Este é o codigo para ler esse mesmo ficheiro.

```
private List<Product> ProcessImport(string path)
{
    XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(path);
    List<Product> products = xDocument.Descendants("product").Select
        (p => new Product()
        {
           Id = Convert.ToInt32(p.Element("id").Value),
           Name=p.Element("name").Value,
           Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(p.Element("quantity").Value),
           Price = Convert.ToInt32(p.Element("price").Value),
           Description = p.Element("description").Element("comment")


        }).ToList();

    foreach(var product in products)
    {
        var productInfo = db.Products.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id.Equals(product.Id));
        if (productInfo != null)
        {
            productInfo.Id = product.Id;
            productInfo.Name = product.Name;
            productInfo.Quantity = product.Quantity;
            productInfo.Price = product.Price;
            productInfo.Description= product.Description;


        }

        else 
        {


            db.Products.Add(product);
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return products;


}
```

Este código funciona. Só que tem um pequeno problema é que ele só lê a primeira description.
E eu queria que ele lê-se as duas descriptions. Provavelmente é uma alteração simples de se fazer, mas eu não tenho ideias de como a executar.

Eu sei que o ideal era criar duas tabelas e depois fazer a ligaçao entre elas.
Mas se me conseguirem ajudar a ler estes dois roots, já é demais.

Obrigado!

Comment: dois nós com o mesmo nome não é muito funcional, seria melhor ter `<descriptons><description>...</description><description>...</description></descriptions>`. Esse xml não seria deserializado corretamente para um classe

Comment: Se você pode alterar a estrutura do XML, faça como o colega apontou.

Comment: @Andre Conseguiu evoluir?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo ainda não, eu não posso alterar a estrutura do XML, mas estou a tentar de outra forma.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode unir as descrições utilizando o método `Join()` da classe string. Eu modifiquei seu código para demonstrar abaixo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Linq;
    
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    static List<Product> db = new List<Product>(); //apenas para siMular dados incluídos no DbSet de produtos
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        ProcessImport("");
    }
    
    private static List<Product> ProcessImport(string path)
    {
    //XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(path);
        XDocument xDocument= new XDocument(  
            new XElement("products",  
                new XElement("product",
                    new XElement("id", "1"),
                    new XElement("name", "Ball"),  
                    new XElement("price", "15"),  
                    new XElement("quantity", "2"),  
                    new XElement("description",
                        new XElement("comment", "aaa")),  
                    new XElement("description",
                        new XElement("comment", "bbb")),   
                    new XElement("age", 
                        new XElement("number", "12"))  
                    )
            )  
        ); 
        List<Product> products = xDocument.Descendants("product").Select
            (p => new Product()
            {
               Id = Convert.ToInt32(p.Element("id").Value),
               Name=p.Element("name").Value,
               Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(p.Element("quantity").Value),
               Price = Convert.ToDouble(p.Element("price").Value),
               Description = string.Join(",", p.Descendants("description").Select(a => a.Element("comment").Value))
            }).ToList();

        foreach(var product in products)
        {
            //var productInfo = db.Products.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id.Equals(product.Id));
            var productInfo = db.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id.Equals(product.Id));
            if (productInfo != null)
            {
                productInfo.Id = product.Id;
                productInfo.Name = product.Name;
                productInfo.Quantity = product.Quantity;
                productInfo.Price = product.Price;
                productInfo.Description= product.Description;
            }
            else 
            {
                //db.Products.Add(product);
                db.Add(product);
            }

            //db.SaveChanges();
            Console.WriteLine("Produto: " + db[db.Count - 1].Name + " Descrição:  " + db[db.Count - 1].Description + " -> incluído com sucesso");
        }

        return products;
    }
}
```

Você pode ver ele rodando no fiddler [clicando aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lRbYzr)